# Define a macro expanding into quotes

Tags: macros, languages

I need a macro that expands an `argument` into the string `{ "argument"}`. The following macro seems to do the trick:

```
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\{ "{#1}"\}}
```

This macro produces for the input `xyzzy{\myquote{fubar}}` the output `xyzzy{ ”fubar”}` which is what I expect.

However, the macro seizes to work properly once I add the package `ngerman` to my document by writing in the header `\usepackage{ngerman}`. Now the input `xyzzy{\myquote{fubar}}` no longer produces the expected output, but instead results in an error when running `latex`:

```
! ngerman: The command "fubar is undefined.
```

I have tried to modify the macro with

```
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\{ \noexpand"{#1}\noexpand"\}}
```

This gets rid of the error, but the quotes `"` are not displayed at all anymore. The observed output becomes `xyzzy{ fubar}` instead of the expected one (the quotes are simply missing).

How do I need to write the macro that produces the expected output even in the presence of the `ngerman` package?

**[Edit] Clarification:** The macro is needed as a marker for a post-processor. Thus, there must not be typographical quotes, but regular double quotes.**[/Edit]**

Comment: The `ngerman` package is obsolete, use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead. This will also solve the error.

Comment: Use the `csquotes` package.

Comment: What about `\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\{ ``#1''\}}`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` indeed solves the issue. `csquotes` is not needed.

Comment: @user8472: However, with `csquotes` you gain independence from the loaded font as well as other language packages that may turn `"` into an active character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ngerman`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ngerman) package is obsolete and should be replaced with the [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package loaded with the `ngerman` option.

As the default font Computer Modern creates still not the up-quotes `"` but the English closing quotes `”` you should us the `T1` font encoding (you should use it anyway for a German text) and the [`lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) fonts (or whatever font you prefer).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or libertine …
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\{"{#1}"\}}
\begin{document}
\myquote{fubar}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The excellent `csquotes` package provides a convenient interface to all kinds of quotation problems. Main purpose is typographically correct quotation, but it also provides commands to directly access all kinds of quotation characters.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\{\textquotedblleft{#1}\textquotedblleft\}}

\begin{document}

  Text in \enquote{typographischen Anführungsstrichen} oder \myquote{anderen Anführungsstrichen}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly he doesn’t want typographical correct quotes but `"` (and all enclosed in `{` and `}`).

Comment: Yes, I need the regular quote character `"`. The `{` and `}` are easy to add (I have just added them for completeness to my question).

Comment: @user8472: See updated answer